# Openpyxl in Spyder

Tags: spyder, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl in spyder IDE to create a new excel workbook. The program runs with no error, however no excel workbook was created.

I copied the code into sublime text, and ran the code in command prompt and it worked perfectly good, with the new excel created

Can someone please explain what i am doing wrong in spyder and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck with the same problem. To resolve it I verified the Python interpreter's version used by my Spyder (there were some of them on my computer). I found out that it wasn't using the one I needed it to. So I changed it to the appropriate version's one with the followed installation of the lacking Spyder kernels with `python -m pip install spyder-kernels`  and all the specific modules I needed to complete my tasks.
Hope the advise to be useful. Have a nice day.